# Ajax ModalPopupExtender not modal in IE7

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a `ModalPopupExtender`, so when a user clicks on a button on the main site, a popup appears for them to enter data. In IE8 there are no issues, it's perfectly modal and none of the buttons on the main page can be clicked. In IE7, the popup appears but is not modal, so I can still click buttons behind the popup window.

I know it's an issue with the popup extender in IE7, I have looked around and there doesn't seem to be a straightforward workaround? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function pageLoad()
{
  var bge = $get("<your ModalPopupExtender ID>_backgroundElement");
  if (bge)
     bge.style.zIndex = -1;
}
```

[ModalPopup - click links outside of the modal region?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1293869.aspx/2/10)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using the correct DOCTYPE as this problem is usually caused because of this in IE7. [Check this link out](http://blog.rameshbhaskar.com/2008/03/03/fixing-modalpopupextender-doctype-problems/). Good luck!